# how do I add the same 3 characters to all of the file names in a directory with powershell -not as a prefix

Tags: windows

I want to add 3 characters eg "-94" to the end of a file name to all of the files in a wordperfect directory. There are many directories with different years and I will be doing the same with each year
e.g NanSloan.wpd would be changed to NanSloan-94.wpd  (as well as all of the other files in the 1994 directory.
I would like to use Powershell to do this

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard, so I'll give you general guidance - try something first and repost when you have a specific question and youv'e tried google.  You're going to use the Get-ChildItem command on the directory, and for each item within the directory use a where clause to select just the .wpf files, and within the properties of the files you'll have everything you need - the original name, the parent dir name, and the extension.  Use move-item to rename it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*wpd" | rename-item -NewName {$_.name-replace '.wpd','-94.wpd'}

Edit: You can add the -Recurse parameter to apply to subfolders

Regards

Comment: thank you Z. When I tried the above solution, Powershell just hung.

Comment: I tried PS C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015> Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "wpd" -Recurse | rename-item -NewName {"$($_.BaseName) -2015.wpd"}
PS C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015>

Comment: this seemed to run (v 5 with Windows 10 Pro) but there were no file changes. I also tried this without the path, being I had changed directories already to where I was going to rename.